# Enforces laws or enforces law?

Tags: phrase-usage

Generally speaking, say about the laws pertaining to something, should we say "enforces law" or "enforces laws"? I have a weird feeling about the second one, that it is not right. I have included the question which sparked this doubt in my mind as situation below

> "Do you know who enforces laws in the sea?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you want to say.

Law and laws may have a slightly different meaning.

- One law, two laws - meaning a certain binding rule about some behaviour. In your example, someone enforcing laws on sea would be someone dealing with these laws, considering them as many different rules. "The" laws that are significant on sea - as opposed to for example perhaps grazing rights for cattle (not a lawyer here) - need the article.

  > Who enforces (the) laws on sea.

But I suspect you mean:

- The entire set of rules as an entity. But as the entity is unique you need the article "the" (it is somewhat optional in the example above):

  > Who enforces *the law* on sea?

Comment: Who enforces the law on **the** sea?

Comment: Well, could be "on sea" as opposed to "on land", too, couldn't it?